# Can you programmatically show/hide geometry of a 3D OBJ model?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, three.js

Total 3D noob here. My understanding is that the OBJ represents the geometry of a 3D model while a file like MTL represents the texture/skin of a model. What I would like to know is if there is a way to generate an OBJ model with different "layers" that we can programmatically show and hide? essentially morphing the shape of a model? If the answer is yes, can three.js handle this type of situation?

Comment: Why not just generate multiple OBJ's and switch between them? You can't disable/enable geometries, but you can use materials to make certain geometries visible and invisible (make certain parts transparent, etc).

Comment: Yeah having multiple obj files was the backup plan. Thanks.

Comment: That actually not a very good suggestion. One OBJ with different material (MTL) applied to it is good enough. @MatZero you are asking a yes/no question and the answer is yes.

Comment: Depending on your goals, you might even want to do both. E.g. I have a dice rolling app where the user can customize the colors of the dice. Each layer that can be customized changes the values on a different material each of which is applied to different submodels.